# How to write a user request initialization in Java REST API along with Spring?

Tags: java, spring, rest, api, spring-mvc

I'm new to Spring based java REST API development. I have to implement a Controller class method which creates a new user request. The final application is a chat service and as the first step I have to create a new user request which is sent to the application to start chatting. How can I implement this in my controller class?

Comment: Parker, this is such a broad question. And clearly you have done no googling. I can give you the hint. Google Spring Boot Rest tutorial

Comment: this is a good start: https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

Comment: I have searched. But the thing is there are tutorials for normal HTTP methods. All I need to know is how to implement a method that initializes a user request. It is different from regular POST method I think.

Comment: @Parker Do you need some rest client for testing purposes?

Comment: Yes I hope to use Postman for that